# How to make a singleton empty immutable "type-safe" collection in Kotlin?

Tags: java, types, kotlin, type-conversion, type-inference

I curate some immutable collections in Java and now Kotlin.  I often create a singleton instance of an empty immutable collection, since Java has type erasure and that instance is the same and can be safely shared for all collections.

In Java, you can create a non-generic singleton object and wrap it in a function to let the type inference work with any type when called from generic type-safe code.  I took this technique from the [java.util.Collections class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--):

```
//                      v-No generic types specified-v
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new Collections.EmptyList();

//                   v-------v-- generic type "passes through"
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

So here's my own Java code which should look very similar (and works):

```
public static final Xform EMPTY = new SourceProviderIterableDesc<>(Collections.emptyList());

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Xform<T> empty() {
    return (Xform<T>) EMPTY;
}
```

Here it is converted to Kotlin:

```
private val EMPTY: Xform<Nothing> = SourceProviderIterableDesc(emptyList())
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
internal fun <T> empty(): Xform<T> =
        EMPTY as Xform<T>
```

And I get this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.organicdesign.fp.xform.XformTest.construction(XformTest.kt:529)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type org.organicdesign.fp.xform.Xform<T>
```

How do I make the add-a-type-to-something-with-no-type trick work in Kotlin?  Also, is there a name for this?

Notes: If I use `listOf()` instead of `emptyList()` in Kotlin, I get the same error.

Comment: This looks like an initialization order issue.  Is `EMPTY` in a companion object?

Comment: Yes, but it's a companion object to an abstract class.  I just moved it and the wrapper function to top-level in file, but same issue.

Comment: Oh, you might be right about init order.  I've got circular definition: `internal open class SourceProviderIterableDesc<T>(private val list: Iterable<T>) : Xform<T>(empty())`  I probably need to make a separate class/object of SourceProviderIterableDesc for the empty.

Comment: The circular definition was the problem.  Thank you @LouisWasserman!  If you write up even a 1-sentence "answer" I'll up-vote and accept it.